# SSIS asynchronous component source code?

Tags: asynchronous, ssis, components, union

I'm building a custom SSIS data flow component that, as part of its process, takes multiple inputs and rolls them into a single output (along the lines of what the UNION ALL component does). I'm having a little bit of trouble implementing the runtime methods and having been looking for source code for asynchronous transformations that use multiple inputs that I can use as a model for my own code.

Does anyone know of available source code or have their own code they'd be willing to share with me to help get me on the right track? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'd look at the [Programming Samples](http://msftisprodsamples.codeplex.com/) from MS's IS team as well as the [Community Transform](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/). Some of those are open source so if you can find one that's async, you should be able to see what you're missing.

My half-remembered logic is that you'll need to look at all the [InputCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtscomponentmetadata100.inputcollection.aspx)s for a given [IDTSComponentMetaData100](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtscomponentmetadata100.aspx) and then work with that data.

Comment: I've looked at the programming samples in both places, but the MS sample code is from 2004, which makes me a little nervous, and the components which have available source code on both of those sites are very different from what I'm trying to do. I've already looked through a number of the components, but none of them have helped me gain insight into the particular problems I'm facing dealing with asynchronous data flow and multiple inputs.